# Is there any alternative of history.length to upgrade react-router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, remix.run

I want to upgrade the `react-router` package to `v6`. It has a dependency on the `history` package, and in the `history` package roadmap, the document says `history.length` will be deprecated and even deleted soon. You can take a look https://github.com/remix-run/history/issues/689

I wonder if there are other alternatives for using `history.length` in my code while upgrading the `react-router` package to the latest version.

As an example, one of my usage of it:

```
  import { useHistory } from 'react-router';

  const history = useHistory();

  const onGoBack = () => {
    if (history.length > 2) {
      history.goBack();
    } else {
      history.push('/portfolio');
    }
  };
```

Comment: Well, in RRDv6 the `history` object is abstracted away anyway and not exposed out. You'll need some custom components to continue using a custom `history` object. That said, you may need to instead just maintain your own "history stack" in app state. I implemented something similar in Redux so I could peek at the "previous" location in the app.

Comment: Thanks, @DrewReese, for your helpful answer. I will implement an approach like storing this data in the context.